# Sizing of wxPython Wizard

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am creating a wizard dialog with several pages using wxPython. I am having trouble laying out the controls because the size of each page is at least as big as the biggest wizard page. E.g. if my wizard has three pages, and page three has more controls/widgets than the other two, then page two and three have a lot of extra space because the wizard calculates its size based on page 3 (as it's the biggest.) Pages one and two look really sloppy.

I read this in the documentation of the wizard class, which leads me to believe that it's not possible to have a custom page size for each wizard page:

> The wizard is laid out using sizers and the page area sizer is the
>   place-holder for the pages. All pages are resized before being shown
>   to match the wizard page area.
>
> Page area sizer has a minimal size that is the maximum of several
>   values. First, all pages (or other objects) added to the sizer.
>   Second, all pages reachable by repeatedly applying WizardPage.GetNext
>   to any page inserted into the sizer.
>
> Third, the minimal size specified using SetPageSize and FitToPage .
>   Fourth, the total wizard height may be increased to accommodate the
>   bitmap height. Fifth and finally, wizards are never smaller than some
>   built-in minimal size to avoid wizards that are too small.
>
> The caller can use Sizer.SetMinSize to enlarge it beyond the minimal
>   size. If RESIZE_BORDER was passed to constructor, user can resize
>   wizard and consequently the page area (but not make it smaller than
>   the minimal size).
>
> It is recommended to add the first page to the page area sizer. For
>   simple wizards, this will enlarge the wizard to fit the biggest page.
>
> For non-linear wizards, the first page of every separate chain should
>   be added. Caller-specified size can be accomplished using
>   Sizer.SetMinSize . Adding pages to the page area sizer affects the
>   default border width around page area that can be altered with
>   SetBorder .

Does anybody have a solution or workaround that will allow my wizard pages to be sized only according to what is on the current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds correct to me. The documentation does indeed seem to indicate that what you want to do is not possible with the wizard widget. You can roll your own wizard though. Just create a series of panels and hide the later pages or create the subsequent pages as you go through the wizard.

I wrote up a tutorial on rolling your own wizard that you're welcome to use as a starting place:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/wxpython-how-to-create-a-generic-wizard/

Of course, having a wizard that is changing its size as you go through it would be distracting and is not normal wizard behavior. You might want to re-think how you're laying out your controls or put the widgets on the large page into a scrolled panel widget so it's the same size as the other two.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to create my own wizard. Thanks for the reference.